# change root directive value in server block with root directive in location block

Tags: nginx

I have set a default directory for the `nginx` to look for the files, but when I try to access a certain location nginx such as `/` looks the default root folder `/var/www/html/LiveStream/LiveStream-backend` instead of what I specified in the location block `/var/www/html/LiveStream/LiveStream-frontend/users/build` for further detail my nginx configuartion file

```
log_format upstreamlog '$server_name to : $upstream_addr [$request]'
            'upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time'
            'msec $msec request-time $request_time';
upstream load_balance{
     ip_hash;
    server  localhost:3016;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ethiolive.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ethiolive.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    
    add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;   
    #SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
    #root /var/www/html/LiveStream/LiveStream-frontend;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    root /var/www/html/LiveStream/LiveStream-backend;
    server_name ethiolive.net www.ethiolive.net;
    
    location /api/ {
        root /var/www/html/LiveStream/LiveStream-backend;
        #alias /var/www/html/LiveStream/LiveStream-backend/public/;
        proxy_pass http://load_balance;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host  $host;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
                proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128; 
        proxy_set_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    }
    location / {
        root /var/www/html/LiveStream/LiveStream-frontend/users/build;
        #add_header Content-Type text/plain;
                #return 200 'hello';
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    location /admin {
        
        alias /var/www/html/LiveStream/LiveStream-frontend/admin/build/;        
                index index.html index.htm;
        #add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        #return 200 index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location /socket/ {
                proxy_pass http://load_balance/socket.io/;
        proxy_redirect          off;

                proxy_http_version      1.1;
                proxy_set_header        Upgrade                 $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Connection              "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
        proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128; 
    }               
    location /socket.io/{
                # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;

                proxy_pass http://load_balance/socket.io/;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
            proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128; 
    }
}
```